# Android link url image : how check link die

Tags: android, android-image

i have problem, when load image, image is die. How check image is die.
[image]
thank

Comment: do you mean link is error?

Comment: Where is the image loaded from? How do you display it? Please provide more information.

Comment: what you mean? explain with detail

Comment: link images show same before. how know link image die ?

Answer (score -2):

If you are trying to load images from the internet and place them inside a view, but they are crashing you could use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). Picasso will let you load images from the internet, and if no image is present you can use a placeholder image instead. Picasso wont crash if you have a placeholder and a null image from the internet.